# Rubiks Cube in WebGL

Tags: html, 3d, webgl

I have one simple rotating cube in WebGL (each face of cube has different colors). My task is to create a 4 x 4 x 4 rubiks cube instead of just a normal cube. Anyone know how I would go about doing that? Would I create 64 cubes from one of the cubes I have or is there another way?

Comment: Can you show us, what you've tried so far and explain why that didn't work for you?

Comment: That is exactly what you would do. You can omit the 8 hidden cubes, and need to make sure all the small cubes rotate around the center of the large cube instead of their own center. If you have specific problems you will need to post a more detailed description with (executable) code samples.